# Can you dodge the blue shell?

Tags: mario-kart-8

I know you could dodge it in Mario Kart Wii by using a mushroom at just the right moment, but is there anyway to dodge it in Mario Kart 8? The same tactic does not appear to work in Mario Kart 8?

So is there any way to dodge it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can boost out of the way or use the environment to avoid the Blue Shell but these methods are unreliable.

The only reliable way to avoid the Blue Shell is to use the Super Horn.

The Super Horn :

[image: Super Horn]

If you pick up the Super Horn you should hold onto it until you need to use it against the Blue Shell.

Comment: I have gotten it in first.

Comment: @zero298 Excuse me?

Comment: Your answer indicates that "You will usually pick up the Super Horn **While in last place**". @zero298 is saying he's gotten the Super Horn while in first, as have I - More frequently than red turtles, but far less frequently than green shells/coins/banana peels. I can't speak for its availability much below 4th place, however, as I haven't spend much time below that yet.

Comment: @TrentHawkins I understand that you don't have to be in last place to pick up a Super Horn, but if you understand how the rubber-banding works you will know that the chance of picking up good items drops dramatically when you are in a low position.

Comment: I'm glad you understand this, but the current wording of the answer could be mistaken to mean that it can only be obtained while in last place. It is entirely possible that this misunderstanding is what prompted zero to comment as he did, and resulted in this conversation.

Comment: From your answer, you make it sound like you only get the horn from being very low in the rankings.  I was adding that unlike the lightning/pirahna/etc, (as far as I can tell) you CAN get the horn high in the rankings as @TrentHawkins was saying.

Comment: I have edited my answer so hopefully it is easier to understand.

Answer (score 6):

Using a Mushroom at the right time does indeed still work to dodge Spiny Shells, with similar timing as previous games (see [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H9yPd2kQylA) at about 0:22). Aside from that you have the Super Horn, though that's not so much a dodge as a block, as well as simply being invincible from something (which you probably won't have while in first place).

Comment: is there any proof of this? (video preferred). I have tried to do this and can never seem to get this to work. Unlike the previous version the shell when it is coming down on you it seems to follow your movement instead of locking to a piece of the ground when coming down.

Comment: Well aside from my experience, there's bunches of internet people agreeing it's possible in various forums. But okay, I just picked out a video from a simple search and linked to it.

Comment: interesting I tried a couple times my self and could never get it. I think I understand how to do it better thanks to the video

Answer (score -1):

Though Caleb's answer is much more favorable, I find that if I don't have any items the best thing to do is slam on the brakes when you see one coming and hope someone behind you passes. It'll slow you down a bit, but much less so than getting nuked.

Comment: Are you sure that works? I seem to remember in previous games (Well, the DS game, any way) that the Blue Shell picks its target, and if you change position before it hits, it doesn't reacquire a new one.

Comment: It could definitely change target in MK Wii.

Comment: It doesn't lock in until it gets up front, so even if it's been fired, you can drop down and it won't pick you if it doesn't get there fast enough.

Answer (score -2):

There is a possibility that you can miss them if you speed through a tunnel like in rainbow road, or be shot out of a cannon.

Comment: This is false.  You can be and I have been hit by a blue shell in Mario kart 8 while in cannon-flight mode.

Comment: That may be true for Mario Kart 8. I haven't actually played that one myself. I do know though that on other versions you can.