# When do I boost to dodge a blue shell?

Tags: mario-kart-8

We've established [in](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/170050/can-you-dodge-the-blue-shell) [numerous](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/61835/is-there-any-way-to-avoid-the-blue-shell-in-mario-kart-7) [posts](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1771/how-to-dodge-the-blue-shell-in-mario-kart-double-dash/) that you can boost out of a Blue Shell or Super Horn it... But we haven't established *when*.

I've been trying to boost through a Blue Shell, and it yet still hits me while my boost is going, or the boost does not activate at all and I eat (still get hit by) the shell. When/what is the window that I should boost to be able to reliably dodge it?

Comment: You can't *boost* out of a Blue Shell (unless you mean *outrunning* a shell for a while, possible only on 200cc) but you can **Mushroom** evade a Blue Shell. Other forms of boost doesn't seem to work to dodge. [Refer to this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F4U-7sRZ2Kc), I'll try to find some other sources

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [this guide](https://www.nintendolife.com/guides/mario-kart-8-deluxe-blue-shells-how-to-avoid-blue-shells)

> If you hit a boost pad or use a boost Mushroom at **the very moment the Blue Shell is starting its descent and explosion** you may dodge it.

So ideally you will want to boost when the Blue Shell stops spinning is about to crash down on you. Since the blue shell is still hitting you, try to boost slightly later.

However [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/mariokart/comments/ah7g3q/mk8dx_accidentally_avoided_a_blue_shell_with_a/) notes that:

> Plus, on 150cc, it is **not possible to dodge a Blue Shell with a boost pad**. Only a Mushroom can give the speed needed to dodge one.

You can use a horn to destroy the [Blue shell](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_shell) as an alternative:

> In Mario Kart 8 and Mario Kart 8 Deluxe, it is possible to use the new Super Horn item to destroy blue shells

Comment: I think the boost pad no longer work on MK8

Answer (score 2):

Boost only when the blue shell is right about to crash down on you, but haven't emitted any blue particles yet.